# PHP Error: Undefined Offset: 1 - LemonStand Product Export

Tags: php

I keep getting the following error when trying to export product images in LemonStand:

```
Phpr_PhpException: Undefined offset: 1. In /public_html/store/modules/shop/classes/shop_productexport.php, line 158
```

Here's the code in question:

```
    // Images should be separated by newlines, and each should be in
    //  in {disk_name}|{real_name} format
    protected static function get_images_for_export($row, $base_path = 'images', &$images_to_export = null)
    {
        if (empty($row['images']))
            return $row;

        $image_paths = explode("\n", $row['images']);
        $row['images'] = array();
        foreach ($image_paths as $image_path)
        {
            list($disk_name, $file_name) = explode('|', $image_path, 2);
            $new_name = preg_replace('/[^\w_\.-]+/u', '_', $row['sku'].'-'.$file_name);

            $row['images'][] = $base_path.'/'.$new_name;
            $images_to_export[$disk_name] = $new_name;
        }

        $row['images'] = join(",", $row['images']);
        return $row;
    }
```

Line 158 is:

```
list($disk_name, $file_name) = explode('|', $image_path, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$image_path` doesn't contain a `'|'` so when exploding it, the result only consist 1 item (`ofsset 0`) and the second item (`ofsset 1` trying to be stored in `$file_name`) doesn't exist.

So your solution would be either to make sure the `$image_path` contains the necessary `'|'` or to handle `$image_path`'s without a `'|'` differently.